# How to calculate rows in foreach loop recursive?

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, foreach

This code below returns category tree.

How can I get the count of the products in each category that has sub categories? I mean to sum values in each subcategory.

Until now I succeed to get the count only for the last level of child category:

```
function menuList($data, $parent = 0 ){
    static $i = 1;
    $tab = str_repeat(' ',$i);
    if($data[$parent]){
        $html = $tab.'<ul id="menu'.$i.'">';
        $i++;
        $count=0;

        foreach($data[$parent] as $v){
            $id = $v->id;
            $categoryname=$v->bg_category;
            if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['active_product_categories'])){
                 $q='select distinct product_id from products_to_categories where category_id="'.$id.'"';
                 $res=mysql_query($q) or die());
                 $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($res);
                 $count='( '.$num_rows.' )';
            }
            $child = menuList($data, $v->id);
            $html .= $tab.'<li>';
            $html .= '<a href="'.$v->WebSite.'/shop/index.php?offers='.$id.'">'.$categoryname.' '.$count.' </a>';

            if($child){
                $i–;
                $html .= $child;
                $html .= $tab;
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= $tab.'</ul>';
        return $html;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$query = mysql_query('select * from products_categories where visible="1" group by bg_category order by bg_category ASC');

while($r=mysql_fetch_object($query)){
    $data[$r->parent][] = $r;
}

$menu = menuList($data);
echo $menu;
```

Please have a look at the screenshot.

Here is the screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zwgvoz&s=8#.U957sizlrDc

[image]

Comment: where did `menuList` function finish? because I can't see its closing curly bracket

Comment: sorry, I have no reputation to add sreenshot, but basicaly menu categories looks like this:
Electronics ?count -> Phones ?count -> Mobiles (10) Smartphones (20)
Total count for Phones should be 30, for Elecronics also 30, but I can not display it..

Comment: just before the last query and while..

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zwgvoz&s=8#.U957sizlrDc here is screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try to write two classes, below I've added examples in pseudo code:

```
Class Menu
{
  private $aSubMenus
  public function __construct()
  public function getNumberOfItems()
  public function addMenuItem()
  public function getHTML()
  public function load($menuID)
}

Class MenuItem
{
  public function __construct()
  public function getHTML()
}
```

Comment: Erik can you please implement it in the code to show me how?thanks

Comment: pff.. That is a lot to ask for, I'll add some pseudo code to help you on your way:

Comment: I've changed my answer to include some pseudo code I would use..
if you separate the loading and data collection from the html generation, it will be a much easier problem..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know your table's structure, but why don't you fix it in SQL:

```
  $q = 'SELECT parent_id, parent_name, count(child_id) FROM your_table GROUP BY parent_id';
```

And only then build up your HTML view.
This code is extremely approximate.

Comment: Yarren, I dont want to count child categories. I want to count products in categories and I count them but only in last deep child category.. Please look at the sreen shot link..

Comment: yeah, I see that. Any way such thing as counting entries from DB much easier to do in DB. In such a way you can count whatever you want, including items in each category.

Comment: Yarren, I can and I do count products in categories with this query:
$q='select distinct product_id from products_to_categories where category_id="'.$id.'"';
but it counts directly connecte product to category.. How to sum products from all child categories and add them to the mother category.. this is the question and I believe all needed information is posted above.. but I can provide additional if needed..

Comment: could you provide your tables structure?

Comment: Yarren, basicaly 3 tables are involved:
1. products_categories
2. products
3. products_to_categories
Which one you need?

Comment: sorry for delay) It's easy to do it with 2 tables))) Try this: $q = 'select p.cat_id, count(p.prod_id), (select parent from product_categories WHERE id=p.cat_id) as parent from products_to_categories p group by p.cat_id;' - it'll give you a list of categoryId, is it a child or parent and total of goods in it.